# How to hide field if get_user_meta is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I'm working on a shortcode to show my authors list on WordPress; I managed to make the social networks fields work, but I can't hide them, if the field is empty.

I imagine I need the `if` statement, but I can't seem to find a way to make it works.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
function pippin_list_authors() {

    $authors = get_users(array(
            'orderby' => 'display_name',
            'count_totals' => false,
            'who' => 'authors',
            'id' => ''
        )
    );

    $list = '';


    if($authors) :

        $list .= '<div class="author-list">';

            foreach($authors as $author) :

                $list .= '<table>';

                    $archive_url = get_author_posts_url($author->ID);
                    $list .= '<tr>' .  get_avatar($author->user_email, 100);


                    $list .= '<br><br><a class="author-list-name" href="'. $archive_url . '" title="' . __('Vedi tutti i post ', 'pippin') . $author->display_name . '">' . $author->display_name . '</a><br>';
                    $list.= '<br><br><div class="author-social"><a href="' . get_user_meta( $author->ID, 'facebook', true). '"><i class="fa fa-facebook"><p style="font-size: 0; color: transparent;">'.A.'</p></i></a>';

                    $list .= '<a href="https://twitter.com/' . get_user_meta($author->ID, 'twitter', true). '"><i class="fa fa-twitter"><p style="font-size: 0; color: transparent;">'.A.'</p></i></a>';
                    $list .= '<p class="author-bio" style="max-height: 103px; overflow: hidden; ">' . get_user_meta($author->ID, 'description',  true) . '</p>';
                    $list .= '<div class="author-archive" style="text-align: center;"><a href="'. $archive_url . '" title="' . __('Vedi tutti i post ', 'pippin') . $author->display_name . '">' . __('Vedi tutti i post', 'pippin') . '</a></div>';

                $list .= '</tr></table>';

            endforeach;

        $list .= '</div>';

    endif;

    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('authors', 'pippin_list_authors');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the variable `$authors` is empty use the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) function.

Try this:

```
if(!empty($authors)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry i meant `if(!empty($authors))`. The function `get_users()` returns an array with the users filtered by the array argument. If it returns an empty array it should be check with `empty()` function.

Comment: Still doesn't work... maybe I got issues on where I put the string

Comment: Can you check what `$authors` has inside?

Comment: You mean this? 
`$authors = get_users(array(
   'orderby' => 'display_name',
   'count_totals' => false,
   'who' => 'authors',
   'id' => ''
  )
 );`

Comment: I mean check if that function actually returns an empty string when it returns no users or if it has some kind of information saying `0 users found` or something like that. If you're saying the code inside the `if statement` is still be rendering even when there's no users the problem has to be in the `if condition`. Check what the `get_users()` function returns when there's no users and you'll be able to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your functions if possible.
 Create function for every social link and other user metas like this:

```
$facebook_link = get_user_meta( $author->ID, 'facebook', true);
```

then call it in this way:

```
<?php if ($facebook_link !=='') { ?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $facebook_link; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `get_user_meta` exist in DB, but isn't value, it still return no empty array so **empty($our_meta)** - will not help.
Bcz return `array( [0] => string("") );`

> Empty string, but this empty value is in the array, so it will show
> that the array is not empty.

Use `get_user_meta($id, $key, true)` it return **''** and empty() will work as it should.

`get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );`

> **$single(boolean)** If set to true, the function will return the value of the meta field, if left false, then the value of the meta
> field will be returned in an array. This parameter has no meaning if
> the $key parameter has not been specified.
> **Default: false**

**- If $single = true**

- string/array - if the meta field exists.
- '' - when the metafield does not exist.

**If $single = false**

- an array of all metafield values - when the metafield exists.
- array() - when the meta field does not exist.